# Enable SSL pinning in ionic 3 using ionic-native http

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement SSL pinning in ionic3 using @ionic-native http.
I have copied the certificate(.cer) file inside **platforms/android/assets**  folder. And i try to run the following code and getting the error saying: 
***You must add at least 1 certificate in order to pin to certificates***
can any one help why i am getting this error?

```
private getHtpRequest(url: string){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             this.htp.enableSSLPinning(true);
              this.htp.post(url, {}, {'Content-Type': 'application/json','reqId': Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1).toString()}) 
              .then(
                (res: any) => {
                  this.results = res.json();
                // Dismiss the loader and return response back.
                resolve(this.results)
                },
                (error: any) => {
                // Dismiss the loader and return error back.
                reject(error)
                }
              )

            });
          }
```

Comment: can someone delete the spam of sunil?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have added to the assets folder but, try with the alternative way first.

> As an alternative, you can store your .cer files in the
>   **www/certificates** folder.

So, just create a certificates folder in your www folder and add the certificates.

Note: please make sure you enable SSL Pinning before making the call, eg:

```
this.http.enableSSLPinning(true);
```

I hope this help.

Comment: hi wils..sorry for the late reply. I have added but i can able see all https (traffic) requests in burp suit tool. If SSL pinning is working, it should not see the https traffic right..

Comment: Hi @vishnu I have updated the example. You need to enable the SSL Pinning before make your call, please see the example I've added.